# How to count consecutive values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

At this moment I have this formula that counts consecutive values:

```
=IF(AB5=0;0;IF(OR(AND(AB4>=100;AB5>=100);AND(AB4<=-100;AB5<=-100));AC4+1;1))
```

Basically it does this:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        1
-110        2
-110        3
-100        4
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         1
150         2
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        1
-150        2
0           0
0           0
```

But I want it to do this:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        0
-110        0
-110        0
-100        4
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         0
150         2
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        0
-150        2
0           0
0           0
```

Or this:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        4
-110        0
-110        0
-100        0
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         2
150         0
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        2
-150        0
0           0
0           0
```

What is the formula to make this possible ?

I prefer not to have to add more columns since the file is already big...

Using only a formula to do this would be the best thing to do.

Thanks.

Comment: What's in column AC?

Comment: Try using my version 1 to create the second version yourself.

Comment: The values on the right are in column AC.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a match formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(ABS(AB5)>=100,AB4=0),MATCH(0,AB6:AB$1048576,0),0)
```

**EDIT**

Clearly this is slow for 1,000,000 cells. The inexact match is faster:

```
=IF(AND(AB5>=100,AB4=0),MATCH(0,AB6:AB$1048576,-1),IF(AND(AB5<=-100,AB4=0),MATCH(-100,AB5:AB$1048576,1),0))
```

[image]

**Discussion**

Why is Match so slow when on the face of it, it should be only searching a few cells ahead for a match? I am wondering if it is because Match copies the whole range to be searched to a temporary array? Generally this might be a good strategy, but in the particular case when the matching value is near the beginning of the range and the range is very large, it is a bad one.

One more possible approach would be to determine the longest sequence using Frequency (this is fast), then limit the range to be searched using Index, something like:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(ABS(A:A)>=100,ROW(A:A)),IF(A:A=0,ROW(A:A))))
```

in B1 then

```
...MATCH(0,AB6:INDEX(A:A,ROW()+B$1),0)
```

Comment: This formula does the job, but only for very small samples of data... I have 1 million cells... I changed those 1048576 to 1 million but it is still to slow... It would take days for Excel to finish processing the whole thing. Can you change it to work faster ?

Comment: If there was a way to make the search around the sequences, limiting the search on values and making the zero the limits of the current sequence... it would be like a dynamic range or something like that.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the best I can do - limiting the range in some way would also need some sort of lookup, so you would be back to square one. Disappointing that it is so slow though, because it should only be searching for a few rows ahead. It is worth asking the question of why you want the AC values as shown e.g. if you want to use it to count the number of sequences you might be able to use a different approach?

Comment: On second thoughts, it would be worth trying the inexact search version of Match as well. This does a binary search. On the face of it, would not be faster (still need about 20 probes for 1,000,000 cells) but on testing it is a lot faster - will add it to my answer.

Comment: I will try to make the dynamic range idea using something like COUNTIF($B$5:B5,"blue") where the mixed reference changes with an IF inside... Something like COUNTIF(IF(...), ABS(...)). I do not mind going back to square one. I would really like to find something that works... Any addition is welcome. I'am thinking that the problem is the match function. In everything I know (programing) this function is always heavy.

Comment: Tom, basically your formula has a big range, or array. If we could find a substitute for this part AB$1048576 than it would do what I was thinking... We just have to find the next zero after a sequence to limit the range of the current sequence being searched. I am giving you ideas because I think you could find a better, more efficient solution than I, because i'm not an Excel expert.

Comment: OK, yes I agree with what you're saying, but it's just finding a way to do it. After a bit of a struggle I have found an inexact match formula that seems to work - it's not perfect, but a lot quicker than the exct match.

Comment: I have also mentioned that I do not want a 3rd column.

Comment: FYI you can delete column AC, that is just the data that you provided as a check. The only other thing I can think of is if you can put an upper limit on the size of a set of consecutive values, but anything else will be tomorrow anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for the 3rd column comment. But still, I went with that solution, the one of the 3rd column, although it is not want I really wanted, but it's the best one... Still, you got your upvote, maily for the first formula that works for some range sizes. Thank you very much for your work Tom.

Answer (score 1):

### Consecutive counting Version 1

I don't know how to solve your problem with excel, it could be probably done with some array formula which would drastically slow down your even now slow workbook. Therefore I have written a VBA version.
Before you use it you should carefully change the values of the first **three** variables to fit your needs.
Put the following code into a **module**:

```
Option Explicit
'-- Customize BEGIN --------------------

  'Read data from this column, and write to the next, e.g.
  'The AB column is column 28: Read from 28 and write to 29
  Public Const ciCol As Integer = 6

  'The first row of data
  Public Const cLoFirstRow As Long = 5

  'cLoRow is an approximate value e.g. you have 200 rows of data and you
  'estimate that you won't have more than a 1000 in a year, than 1000 is enough,
  'if you have a million then put in a million. The smaller this number the
  'faster the code.
  Public Const cLoRow As Long = 1000
'-- Customize END ----------------------

Sub ConsecutiveCounting1()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'-- Customize BEGIN --------------------
  'The Abs function eliminates the need for a negative value variable.
  Const cLoLimit As Long = 100
'-- Customize END ----------------------
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Dim oRng As Range
  Dim loLastRow As Long
  Dim loTemp As Long
  Dim loF1 As Long 'Row Counter
  loLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, ciCol).End(xlUp).Row
  Set oRng = Range(Cells(cLoFirstRow, ciCol), Cells(loLastRow, ciCol))
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  loTemp = 0
  For loF1 = 1 To oRng.Rows.Count
    If loF1 <> oRng.Rows.Count Then
      If Abs(oRng(loF1, 1)) >= cLoLimit Then
        loTemp = loTemp + 1
        If Abs(oRng(loF1 + 1, 1)) >= cLoLimit Then
          oRng(loF1, 2) = 0
         Else
          oRng(loF1, 2) = loTemp
          loTemp = 0
        End If
       Else
        oRng(loF1, 2) = 0
      End If
     Else 'Last Value
      If Abs(oRng(loF1, 1)) >= cLoLimit Then
        loTemp = loTemp + 1
        oRng(loF1, 2) = loTemp
       Else
        oRng(loF1, 2) = 0
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

And then put the following code in the sheet's **code window**:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim ColumnNumber As Long
  Dim RowNumber As Long
    ColumnNumber = Target.Column
    RowNumber = Target.Row
    If ColumnNumber <> ciCol Then Exit Sub
    If RowNumber > cLoRow Then Exit Sub
  ConsecutiveCounting1
End Sub
```

The code automatically changes the value of the cell in the target column without any formula in the resulting cells what should make it very fast. If this isn't the case, an array version could be written, which would make the code dozens of times faster.

Comment: VBasic2008, your code seems to be a good solution... I got this error though "Runtime error '6'" OverFlow.

Comment: VBasic2008, if you think that an array version would do the job, than you are welcome to write that :) (since I do not know how to program in VBA) The provided code stopped at row 32768, but I need it to work for 1 million rows!

Comment: VBasic2008, you deserve the upvote because your script worked, although with it's limitations...

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the code in the sheet window. The variables ColumnNumber and RowNumber have to be declared as long.